# How can I install fpm (packaging tool) with isolated dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, package-managers

Most guides to installing fpm suggest using `gem`. For example (from sources [1](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html) and [2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fpm-to-easily-create-packages-in-multiple-formats#installing-fpm)):

```
gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc fpm
```

or

```
sudo gem install fpm
```

But I want to isolate and manage fpm's dependencies, separately from system packages and other Ruby tools. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several isolation tools available for Ruby, one of them is rbenv which can be used as follows:

```
sudo apt install rbenv
rbenv install 2.4.1
rbenv local 2.4.1 # enter the environment
gem install fpm
fpm --version
rbenv local --unset # leave the environment
```

**Note:**

There may be ways to make rbenv-based gems easier to run (e.g. not having to enter/exit the environment):

- https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset
- [Can I execute gems from outside an rbenv environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874821)