# Can I execute gems from outside an rbenv environment?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I am able to install and execute a gem as follows:

```
rbenv install 2.4.1
rbenv local 2.4.1 # enter the environment
gem install fpm
fpm --version
```

I was expecting to be able to execute the gem from outside the environment too, something like:

```
rbenv local --unset # leave the environment
rbenv rehash # update shims
fpm --version
```

But instead I get:

```
rbenv: fpm: command not found

The `fpm' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.4.1
```

Have I misunderstood how rbenv shims work? Can I execute a gem from outside an rbenv environment?

Comment: Gems are installed **within a ruby version**. If you switch ruby versions (regardless of what version management tool you're using), the gem will not be installed in that other version. (And if you install it there too, it will be a second/separate installation.)

Comment: related link: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1115

Comment: @TomLord that I understand (but thanks for the clarification!), for some reason I believed that rbenv generated shims that would hop into the environment, execute the gem and leave, without me having to perform those steps

Comment: What would happen if you had a gem installed in two environments? How would it know which environment to "hop into"?

Comment: Moreover, wouldn't that be super confusing if you're in one environment, but running certain commands would automatically "hop into" another environment?

Comment: The whole point of the shim is that, for example, you "switch versions" to `2.4.1`, and can freely add/remove/use gems there. If you then switch into a *different* version (which is presumably what `rbenv local --unset` has done in this case), then you are now isolated to whatever's installed on that ruby version.

Comment: In other words, this is not a bug; it's a feature. This is literally the whole point of what `rbenv` is *supposed* to be doing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments in your Github issue it seems you got the basic idea now; rbenv shims are nothing more than glorified shell scripts that tie a command to a particular currently active Ruby version.

But nothing prevents you from creating your own hard-coded shims. For example, let's say you want this global `fpm` command that is available outside any particular rbenv environment.

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
> rbenv local 2.4.1
> ln -s `rbenv which fpm` ~/.rbenv/bin/fpm24
> rbenv local --unset
> fpm24 --version
1.10.2
```

This will install a "shim" into `~/.rbenv/bin/fpm24` that is a hard-coded pointer to the 2.4.1 gem that rbenv has installed previously. Now this `fpm24` command will work anywhere, as long as you have `~/.rbenv/bin` in your PATH.